# Laravel: Are event handlers sequential?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

If I have multiple listeners on an event, are the processed sequentially or in parallel? (assuming they are not being queued)

If sequentially, are they processed in the order they are defined?

Example:

```
    KidfundEvents\InviteCreated::class => [
        KidfundListeners\SendInviteByEmail::class,
        KidfundListeners\SendInviteByAPNS::class,
        KidfundListeners\AssociateInviteToUser::class,
    ],
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are sequential if they aren't queued. And in order.